# Prevent duplicates in pytest params

Tags: python, pytest

If there's multiple parameters having duplicates, is there a way to disable executing the test with the duplicate parameters.
Note: I have put the minimal snippet to cover the issue I am facing.

test_file.py

```
import pytest

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    """
    Parse the fixture dynamically. 
    """
    for fixture in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if fixture == ("sample_fixture"):
            param_list = load_sample_tests()
            if param_list:
                metafunc.parametrize(fixture, param_list)


def load_sample_tests():
    param_list = []
    for each in ["a", "b", "a", "c"]:
        param_list.append(pytest.param(each, id=each))
    return param_list


def test_one(sample_fixture):
    pass
```

Output:

```
collected 4 items

test_one.py::test_one[a0] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                   [ 25%]
test_one.py::test_one[b] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                    [ 50%]
test_one.py::test_one[a1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                   [ 75%]
test_one.py::test_one[c] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                    [100%]
```

I don't want the test case to be executed two times with `a` param. Is there any parameter or configurations to disable it? or I have to manually deduplicate them?

Comment: `param_list = set(load_sample_tests())`?

Comment: Yeah, that can be done. I assumed that pytest will automatically dedup them as we provide `id` in each param. But, was surprised when it executed all of them.

Comment: You may want to provide the same parameters for example to check for dependencies between tests. I think pytest doesn't want to second-guess your intentions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following function into the plugin helped to de-duplicate the test cases.

```
    def dedup_tests(self, test_list):
        """
        Deduplicate the test case parameters based on param.id

        Args:
            test_list(Generator): Generator of pytest.param

        Yields:
            Generator: De-duplicated pytest.param
        """
        seen_tests = set()
        for each_param in test_list:
            if each_param.id not in seen_tests:
                yield each_param
                seen_tests.add(each_param.id)
```